# How to share django database model between projects in Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, design-patterns

I have following service structure:

```
service1/
    Dockerfile
    manage.py
    settings.py
    ..
service2/
    Dockerfile
    manage.py
    settings.py
    ..
databasemodel/
    Dockerfile
    manage.py
    settings.py
    database/
        models.py
```

Each service and database models has it's own git repository.

How do I share common django database model between them (both services connect to same database). I have implemented manual copying of "database" folder over to service1 and service2, but it feels wrong. I feel like implementing some anti-pattern.

I need setup for:

1) development on local machine (something that would bring up database and both services)

2) deployment so that dev-ops team can deploy each git repo to server

I am very inexperienced with Django and Python and Docker and Git, please do not assume that I know trivial truths. :)

EDIT: I am free to change this structure how I please, however solution should still have git-repo for each service and database models

Comment: This sounds like you need to expose the database in the databasemodel [via an API](https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/creating-apis-with-python-and-flask#connecting-our-api-to-a-database).

Comment: forgetso - this is a good advice, thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you think about the fact that each of these services will each be deployed on their own server, you quickly realise that they need to be exposed to each other via an API layer. There is no other way for them to communicate.

Comment: They can still communicate through DB layer, cant they?! Is this anti-pattern? Like - one service inserts some records in table but other reads out, takes action and updates something? :/

Comment: Yes, they can communicate via the DB layer. There is nothing wrong with this. This would function kind of like a queuing system whereby Service 1 inserts a task into a Queue DB, Service 2 notices the task is present and takes action. So in this case both services would just connect to the DB server and you could copy the DB interface files to each service as common files, as you originally described.